# Python, use of REQUEST for submit-button

Tags: python, post, python-requests, submit

I am trying to submit some data to a PHP-form via Python.

The Webpage is set up like this:

```
<body>
<form action="do_process.php" method="post">

Date: <input type="text" name="Date"><br>
Value old: <input type="text" name="OldVal"><br>
Value new: <input type="text" name="NewVal"><br>

<input type="submit"  name="ClickMe" value="ClickMe">
</body>
```

Where "do_process.php" writes the entered values into a text-file on the server. Doing this manually by clicking on the Button works correctly and the text-file gets updated.

In Python I am using "requests" for getting data from the web-site and posting back to it:

```
def write_data(Date, OldVal, NewVal):
 url='http://mypage.somewhere/display.php'
 payload = {'Date':Date, 'OldVal':OldVal, 'NewVal':NewVal, 'Submit':'ClickMe'}
 res=requests.post(url, data=payload)
 print(res.text)
```

When I call the function in python I get the HTML-listing of the whole page back on res, however the text-file is not getting updated. Also switching to

```
     payload = {'Date':Date, 'OldVal':OldVal, 'NewVal':NewVal, 'ClickMe':'Submit'}
```

did not make any difference.

I guess, I am missing something very obvious, however can't get my eyes on it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are clicking "submit", it calls "do_process.php" and pass all the values of the form to this page, so in your python script you should not call "display.php", you should directly call "do_process.php"

Comment: Doh...
Thanks a lot, this is was the issue!

Comment: @ye_ol_man do not forget to accept the answer then so your topic doesnt show up as unanswered.